# By default how many data points does graphite send/give?

Tags: graphite, whisper

When we request a metric's data-points in graphite say - **http://graphite-server/render?target=&width=1200&height=750&format=json**
 how many data points are retrieved (i.e. how many data-points does it return by default if we don't specify `'from'` and `'until'` parameters?).

1. Does graphite give all the datapoints from the whisper database? or
2. does it give all the data-points that fall under the first retention policy period? or
3. does it return certain number of data-points?

For my local graphite instance I see that by default it returns all the data-points within last 24 hours. But, in my companies server I see that the graphite is returning data-points for last 30 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently, I read somewhere that by default graphite gives/sends data-points of 24hours. 
(In the question, I said I saw data-points of last 30hrs in my companies graphite-instance. But, that's not true (maybe I miss understood it :)). Even the graphite instance in my company by default is sending data-points for last 24hrs :))